# How to remove a table border from a jqGrid cell

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm using the jQuery UI library + CSS as well as the jqGrid CSS for an ASP GridView I have.  The problem I'm running into is that if I add a `<table>` inside my `<ItemTemplate>` I always get a border around the table.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6032362/Capture.PNG

I've tried everything I can think of to get rid of the border and I can't.  I've tried inline CSS and nothing is working.  I even tried to add the following to the jQuery UI CSS file (my table is called controlTable)

```
.ui-widget-content table#controlTable { border: 9px solid red; }
```

It works by adding a think red border around the table.  But the cells still have an internal blue line.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6032362/Capture2.PNG

Any ideas what I can do to get rid of it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Did you know about css keyword `!important`? It's used to force override over declarations that otherwise take priority (priority of css declarations is based on order of placement and precision/specificity of selectors); anyway, try this:

```
.ui-widget-content table#controlTable td { border: 9px solid red !important; }
```

Every time your css like that stubbornly won't be applied (as something else overrides your declaration), try adding `!important` after the value, but before the semi-colon:

border: 9px solid red **!important**;

Also notice the exclamation point! +1

Comment: Thank you Hari.  I've tried that as well.  I must have something really screwed up because I can't get rid of the border.  I'm going to have to try something else unfortunately!  Thanks !!